# How to iterate over all the inodes belong to a filesystem on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

What is the efficient way to get all the inodes for a filesystem? In theory something like fsck would need to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "get" the inodes?

Comment: Querying the superblock would get you points to the start of the inode tables.

Comment: Thanks Marc, i guess this is what i will do

Comment: @Gabe, get the list of used inodes.

Answer (score 1):

`dumpe2fs`, a part of the `e2fsprogs` package, can dump information on inodes in ext* filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Simplest/naive way**: Iterate over all possible values (perhaps all possible 32-bit values) and probe for each of them using either `ilookup5()` or `ilookup()` (depending on your usecase).
2. **For kernel verion 2.4**: Iterate over the list of in use and not in use lists of inodes. These lists will have only those inodes that are valid. The problem with this approach is there does not seem to be any interface provided by VFS layer to access these lists, so you will have to access them directly, which is not a good idea.